# Read and filter files from folders uploaded with Flutter (web and desktop)

Tags: flutter, file, gitignore

I'm trying to upload folder and its content (subfolders and files) in a flutter project (desktop or mobile or web) and put the name of all files to a List to reference the list of file in the folder and sub folders.

But, if .gitignore file is present in the folder i uploaded, i would like to exclude files from gitignore patterns.

Do you you how to manage in dart/flutter gitignore pattern ? Do you know if a lib exists to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: it could be interesting to have something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-gitignore?activeTab=code